# Start HTML video when Colorbox opens/loads

Tags: html, drupal-modules

I've created an image which on click loads a lightbox with a video inside (Drupal 7, Module: Colorbox).

I'd like this video to autoplay once the lightbox is loaded.

Simple enough you may cry! However when I use the autoplay attribute the video starts playing as soon as the page is loaded (despite not being able to see the video) once you click the image and the lightbox loads the video actually pauses.

See: https://www.workbooks.com/video-final

Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/wrj1ka86/1/ (Autoplay issue not affected on JSFiddle due to no Drupal lightbox modules loaded).

How can I get the video to autoplay **only** when the lightbox is loaded?

Comment: If you're using Colorbox, it does have several callbacks that run - (When the lightbox is opening, and when the lightbox has fullyloaded) `onComplete` is the callback you want, from the website: `Callback that fires right after loaded content is displayed. `

Comment: Thanks so I could get a script to fire autoplay when onComplete has ran?

Comment: Yes, in that callback you could run the start method of the HTML video.

Comment: Yes that's when you'd want to run the video autoplay script.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with Javascript so will do some research. Do you have any reference links?